# How do I cluster 3 columns of categorical data?

Tags: clustering, neural-networks, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to form clusters from my data that is purely categorical: Here's an example:

```
Customer ID      Main Product Code     Detailed Product Code
2134             AB 12                 ABZ21
1234             AB 12                 ABZ22
1234             AB 14                 ABZ23
4784             CD 12                 CDZ24
4784             AB 12                 ABZ21
```

I'd like to form clusters around the main product code for a particular customer. 
I'm using R and have seen the literature around k-modes, ROCK, MCA but am having difficulty implementing a solution.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by "cluster" here?

Comment: cluster = form groups of main products (for a particular customer). I want to know that a particular customer, for a main product code, is likely to order detailed product code 'xyz'.

Comment: From your description, it isn't clear that you really want clustering (to 'form groups of main products'). Why not just make tables of counts of main products by customer, & look at things like the % of purchases that go to the modal product, or the odds ratio of 1st to 2nd, or model ranks by counts and estimate the parameters of a power distribution?

Answer (score 1):

For clustering any data-set, the primary requirement is to be able to measure or express distance from one record to any other record.

The sample data you have shared has only text labels, so it cant be used for clustering as-is. However, if you're able to add a concept of "distance" to each record, then, it could be used for clustering. Once you've done this, I recommend using hierarchical clustering to produce a dendogram.

Alternatively, you could use association rule mining to discover relationships such as given main product was purchased, what is the support and confidence that a sub-product would be purchased by the customer. For your data-set, this seems to be more straightforward than clustering.
Here are the rules extracted from your dataset:

```
  lhs                              rhs                           support confidence lift    
1 {Detailed.Product.Code=ABZ22} => {Main.Product.Code=AB 12}     0.2     1          1.666667
2 {Main.Product.Code=AB 14}     => {Detailed.Product.Code=ABZ23} 0.2     1          5.000000
3 {Detailed.Product.Code=ABZ23} => {Main.Product.Code=AB 14}     0.2     1          5.000000
4 {Main.Product.Code=CD 12}     => {Detailed.Product.Code=CDZ24} 0.2     1          5.000000
5 {Detailed.Product.Code=CDZ24} => {Main.Product.Code=CD 12}     0.2     1          5.000000
6 {Detailed.Product.Code=ABZ21} => {Main.Product.Code=AB 12}     0.4     1          1.666667
```